# Dynamically loading assemblies which have references

Tags: c#, .net, clr, appdomain

I'm working on an application which needs to load plugins, which are usually a common interface to a proprietary assembly. The proprietary assembly also has references of its own. However, most boilerplate assembly loading code I can find (write your own plugin interface library, use Activator.CreateInstance, etc) doesn't take into account assemblies with references. For reference, here's the model of what I'm dealing with:

```
Application ---loads--->     FooWare library bridge plugin assembly 
                                                 |
                                                 v
                                             references
                                                 |
                                                 v
                                            FooWare assembly
                                                 |
                                                 v
                                             references
                                                 |
                                                 v
                                           Helper assembly v1.2

            ---loads---> BarWare library bridge assembly
                                        |
                                        v
                                    references
                                        |
                                        v
                                 BarWare assembly
                                        |
                                        v
                                    references
                                        |
                                        v
                                  Helper assembly v1.3
```

I've heard about AppDomains, but I don't really know much about them. Is there a library or something like that which will automatically do this for me, or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: The idea of `AppDomain` is to allow you to unload the assemblies to allow the executing app to stay running. Nevertheless, however you load the Assemblies, you can use `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()` method recursively to load all dependencies.

Comment: @zaitsman will this allow me to load the assemblies the other assemblies reference or will I have to do it recursively? Also does this let me load more than one version at a time?

Comment: You will have to do it recursively, but that logic is quite simple. You can load more than one version into a different app domain. Attempting to load one assembly twice into the same app domain results in .net trying to figure out for you which version to use.